# Adding Labels or Edit boxes as actions of buttons in C#

Tags: c#

"I am using Visual Basic C# 2010 and I want to create a form for shape drawing with three shapes possible namely line,rectangle, ellipse. Initially I display only three buttons with text as 'Line' , 'Rectangle', 'Ellipse'. According to which button i click on, I want labels and edit boxes to appear asking for properties of the shape to draw. For example, if i click on line, I want the label asking for length to appear. And if i have clicked on rectangle, I want the label asking for length and breadth to appear only. So how can i implement these labels as actions of specific button? 
"

I have written this code and my previous problem of how to ask for user input differently for different button clicks is resolved.Thanks to repliers!
Now in this code only thing remaining is to create an area where the shape would be drawn.I cant understand how to do it.Can anyone help?
Why the shape is not getting drawn? Please note that i want to draw the shape on original form and not the pop up form.
please help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ShapeDrawing
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public abstract class SHAPE
        {
            public Pen MyPen = new Pen(Color.Brown, 3.5F);
            public abstract void getparameters();
            public abstract void drawshape(Form1 e);
        }

        public class LINE : SHAPE
        {
            float x1,x2,y1,y2;
            public override void getparameters()
            {
                PopForLine Popup = new PopForLine();
                DialogResult dialogresult = Popup.ShowDialog();
                if (dialogresult==DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        this.x1 = (float)Convert.ToDouble(Popup.Point1XText.Text);
                        this.y1 = (float)Convert.ToDouble(Popup.Point1YText.Text);
                        this.x2 = (float)Convert.ToDouble(Popup.Point2XText.Text);
                        this.y2 = (float)Convert.ToDouble(Popup.Point2YText.Text);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e) 
                    {
                        x1=x2=y1=y2=0;
                    }
                } 
                Popup.Dispose();
            }
            public override void drawshape(Form1 e) 
            {
                Graphics formGraphics=e.CreateGraphics();
                formGraphics.DrawLine(MyPen,x1,y1,x2,y2);
                formGraphics.Dispose();
            }
        }

        class RECTANGLE : SHAPE
        {
            float Length, Breadth;
            public override void getparameters()
            {
                PopForRect Popup = new PopForRect();
                DialogResult dialogresult = Popup.ShowDialog();
                if (dialogresult == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Length = (float)Convert.ToDouble(Popup.LengthText.Text);
                        Breadth =(float) Convert.ToDouble(Popup.BreadthText.Text);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) 
                    {
                        Length = 0;
                        Breadth = 0;
                    }
                }
                Popup.Dispose();
            }
             public override void drawshape(Form1 e)
             {
                Graphics formGraphics = e.CreateGraphics();
                formGraphics.DrawRectangle(MyPen, 0, 0, Length,Breadth);
                formGraphics.Dispose();            
             }
        }

        class ELLIPSE : SHAPE
        {
            float radius1, radius2;
            public override void getparameters()
            {
            PopForEllipse Popup = new PopForEllipse();
            DialogResult dialogresult = Popup.ShowDialog();
            if (dialogresult == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                try
                {
                    this.radius1 = (float)Convert.ToDouble(Popup.SRadText.Text);
                    this.radius2 = (float)Convert.ToDouble(Popup.LRadText.Text);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    radius1 = 0;
                    radius2 = 0;
                }
            }
            Popup.Dispose();
        }
        public override void drawshape(Form1 e)
        {
            Graphics formGraphics = e.CreateGraphics();
            formGraphics.DrawEllipse(MyPen, 0, 0, radius1, radius2);
            formGraphics.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private void LineButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LINE MyLine = new LINE();
        MyLine.getparameters();
        MyLine.drawshape(this);
        MyLine.MyPen.Dispose();
    }

    private void EllipseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ELLIPSE MyEllipse = new ELLIPSE();
        MyEllipse.getparameters();
        MyEllipse.drawshape(this);
        MyEllipse.MyPen.Dispose();
    }

        private void RectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RECTANGLE MyRectangle = new RECTANGLE();
            MyRectangle.getparameters(); 
            MyRectangle.drawshape(this);
            MyRectangle.MyPen.Dispose();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You can use popup windows (forms) to show the labels and textboxes for input when the buttons are clicked. Or you can use panels that you have hidden, and show them when the user clicks one of the buttons.

Comment: You can manage the label text as you click "those 3 buttons".

Comment: @Wolf5 Thanks! I found a related link: http://www.howtosolutions.net/2013/01/creating-a-new-popup-window-in-winform-using-csharp/#.VZD8N_mqqko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this code working and got the job done exactly the way i wanted.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ShapeDrawing
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public abstract class SHAPE
        {
            public Pen MyPen = new Pen(Color.Brown, 3.5F);
            public abstract void getparameters();
            public abstract void drawshape(Form1 e);
            public abstract void description(Form1 e);
            public void enabling(Form1 e) 
            {
                e.RetryButton.Enabled = true;
                e.ExitButton.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        public class LINE : SHAPE
        {
            float x1,x2,y1,y2;
            public override void getparameters()
            {
                PopForLine Popup = new PopForLine();
                DialogResult dialogresult = Popup.ShowDialog();
                if (dialogresult==DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        this.x1 = (float)Convert.ToDouble(Popup.Point1XText.Text);
                        this.y1 = (float)Convert.ToDouble(Popup.Point1YText.Text);
                        this.x2 = (float)Convert.ToDouble(Popup.Point2XText.Text);
                        this.y2 = (float)Convert.ToDouble(Popup.Point2YText.Text);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e) 
                    {
                        x1=x2=y1=y2=0;
                    }
                }
                Popup.Dispose();
            }
            public override void drawshape(Form1 e) 
            {
                Graphics formGraphics = e.ShapeSpace.CreateGraphics();
                formGraphics.DrawLine(MyPen,x1,y1,x2,y2);
                formGraphics.Dispose();
            }

            public override void description(Form1 e) 
            {
                double linelength;
                linelength = Math.Sqrt(((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1)) + ((y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1)));
                e.Description.Text = "This is a line of length " + Convert.ToString(linelength) + " starting from (" + Convert.ToString(x1) + "," + Convert.ToString(y1) + ") to (" + Convert.ToString(x2) + " , " + Convert.ToString(y2)+") .\n";
            }
        }

        class RECTANGLE : SHAPE
        {
            float Length, Breadth;
            public override void getparameters()
            {
                PopForRect Popup = new PopForRect();
                DialogResult dialogresult = Popup.ShowDialog();
                if (dialogresult == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Length = (float)Convert.ToDouble(Popup.LengthText.Text);
                        Breadth =(float) Convert.ToDouble(Popup.BreadthText.Text);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) 
                    {
                        Length = 0;
                        Breadth = 0;
                    }
                }
                Popup.Dispose();
            }
            public override void drawshape(Form1 e)
            {
                Graphics formGraphics = e.ShapeSpace.CreateGraphics();
                formGraphics.DrawRectangle(MyPen, 0, 0, Length,Breadth);
                formGraphics.Dispose();            
            }

            public override void description(Form1 e)
            {
                e.Description.Text = "This is a rectangle of width= " + Convert.ToString(Length) + " and height= " + Convert.ToString(Breadth) + " .\n";
            }
        }

        class ELLIPSE : SHAPE
        {
            float radius1, radius2;
            public override void getparameters()
            {
                PopForEllipse Popup = new PopForEllipse();
                DialogResult dialogresult = Popup.ShowDialog();
                if (dialogresult == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        this.radius1 = (float)Convert.ToDouble(Popup.SRadText.Text);
                        this.radius2 = (float)Convert.ToDouble(Popup.LRadText.Text);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        radius1 = 0;
                        radius2 = 0;
                    }
                }
                Popup.Dispose();
            }
            public override void drawshape(Form1 e)
            {
                Graphics formGraphics = e.ShapeSpace.CreateGraphics();
                formGraphics.DrawEllipse(MyPen, 0, 0, radius1, radius2);
                formGraphics.Dispose();
            }

            public override void description(Form1 e)
            {
                e.Description.Text = "This is an ellipse of width= " + Convert.ToString(radius2) + " and height= " + Convert.ToString(radius1) + " .\n";
            }
        }

        private void LineButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LINE MyLine = new LINE();
            MyLine.getparameters();
            MyLine.drawshape(this);
            MyLine.MyPen.Dispose();
            MyLine.description(this);
            MyLine.enabling(this);
        }

        private void EllipseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ELLIPSE MyEllipse = new ELLIPSE();
            MyEllipse.getparameters();
            MyEllipse.drawshape(this);
            MyEllipse.MyPen.Dispose();
            MyEllipse.description(this);
            MyEllipse.enabling(this);
        }

        private void RectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RECTANGLE MyRectangle = new RECTANGLE();
            MyRectangle.getparameters();
            MyRectangle.drawshape(this);
            MyRectangle.MyPen.Dispose();
            MyRectangle.description(this);
            MyRectangle.enabling(this);
        }

        private void ExitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void RetryButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Description.Text = " ";
            ShapeSpace.Image = null;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a label and on the ButtonClick Event of each button you can set Text property of the label

If circle is clicked

labelName.Text = "Enter the radius";

If Square is clicked

labelName.Text = "Enter the side lenght";

this would help your requirement

Comment: No but then for an ellipse or a rectangle? I need two lengths there.

Answer (score 0):

If this is WPf application and you are using MVVM then on button click you can notify your text property with appropriate text.